# Returning value from callback

Tags: php, callback

After registering a new user, I receive a `selector` and `token` for account verification.
I want to be able to know whether or not a confirmation mail was sent, but I'm having troubles returning the value from the callback. Here's what I have:

```
  try {
      $callback = function ($selector, $token) {
          $msg = "some message";
          if(mail($_POST['email'],"Please verify your account",$msg))
          {
              return "success";
          }
          else
          {
              return "mail_not_sent";
          }
      };
      $auth->registerWithUniqueUsername($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['username'], $callback);
      $output['result']=$callback; //this is the array where I want to store the result in ("success" of "mail_not_sent").
  }
  catch ($e) {
  }
```

Comment: What uses these callbacks? This seems like a silly way of doing things.

Comment: What would you suggest how to do things? I basically want to be able to know when something went wrong. So, or the mail gets sent and the user gets register (=success), or one of those two things fails.

Comment: Why not just return a true/false value (Or a result string) from `$auth->registerWithUniqueUsername`? Callbacks can get rather nasty in php.

Comment: @NikolaiSleta: that didn't work... it throws a bunch of errors like selector and token aren't set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It doesn't look like `Auth::registerWithUniqueUsername()` gives you access to the result of the callback](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth/blob/master/src/Auth.php#L241-L279), so if I had to do this, I would do something like this:

```
$callback_result = '';

$callback = function ($selector, $token) use (&$callback_result) {
    /* Other code here */
    $callback_result = 'whatever';
    /* Other code here */
};

$auth->registerWithUniqueUsername(/* Other args here */, $callback);
$output['result'] = $callback_result;
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! Bit off topic, but still: right now, it's of course possible to have a situation where the email couldn't be send, but the registration went through. Is there a way to make it so that both the sending of the email and the registration should be successful, and if not, none of those two should happen? I'm guessing not, but it's worth a try.

Comment: From the source code of the project you are using (`delight-im/auth`), it does not care what the callback returns, so I am not sure how you would do it. Could you maybe immediately 'unregister' the user if the callback indicated that the e-mail was not successful?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit odd way but:

```
       try {
      $mailFlag = null;
      $callback = function ($selector, $token) use (&$mailFlag) {
          $msg = "some message";
          if(mail($_POST['email'],"Please verify your account",$msg))
          {
              $mailFlag = "success";
          }
          else
          {
              $mailFlag = "mail_not_sent";
          }
      };
      $auth->registerWithUniqueUsername($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['username'], $callback);
      $output['result'] = $mailFlag; //this is the array where I want to store the result in ("success" of "mail_not_sent").
  }
      catch ($e) {
  }
```